# Sending Form Parameters to Web-service using Operations

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, web-services, json

Client-Side I'm trying to capture the fields like this:

```
// Initialize the object, before adding data to it.
//  { } is declarative shorthand for new Object().
var NewSubscriber = { };

NewSubscriber.FirstName = $("#FirstName").val();
NewSubscriber.LastName = $("#LastName").val();
NewSubscriber.Email = $("#Email").val();
NewSubscriber.subscriptionID = $("#subscriptionID").val();
NewSubscriberNewPerson.Password = "NewPassword1";
NewSubscriber.brokerID = "239432904812";

// Create a data transfer object (DTO) with the proper structure.
var DTO = { 'NewSubscriber' : NewSubscriber };

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: "NewSubscriberService.asmx/AddDigitalSubscriber",
data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
dataType: "json"
});
```

Now here's the problem I'm running into. How do I send these parameters and set them in the web service using C# or vb.net if it's easier? Any help is greatly appreciated

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
 {



    public SubNameSpace.WebServiceSubBook.drmProfile _profile;


    [WebMethod]
    public string SetProfileData (object DTO) {
        SetProfile (DTO);


    }
    [WebMethod]
    public class SetProfileData (SubNameSpace.WebServiceSubBook.drmProfile _profile;) {
        this._profile = _profile;


        return "success";
    }
 }
}
```

SetProfile is an operation within the web service. SetProfileRequest is the message in the operation. I want to set certain parameters and then list other parameters in the code-behind file such as:

```
access_time = 30;
```

I'm completely lost...help!

Front-End Coder Lost in C# Translation

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript object's first 'head' id `NewSubscriber` must match your web methods signature, for example:
you are calling `url: "NewSubscriberService.asmx/AddDigitalSubscriber",` with `var DTO = { 'NewSubscriber' : NewSubscriber };`

So you need something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public string AddDigitalSubscriber(NewSubscriber NewSubscriber)
{
    string status = string.Empty;
    // Add Subscriber...
    string emailFromJavascript = NewSubscriber.Email;
    // do something
    return status;
}
```

You will need a class in .NET like the following to match with your javascript object:

```
//... Class in .NET
public class NewSubscriber
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public string Email;
    public int subscriptionID;
    public string Password;
    public string brokerID;
}
```

So the objects match and the names match.

Comment: Got it...totally understand that, but the part I'm failing to grasp is once I'm in:     `[WebMethod]
public string AddDigitalSubscriber(NewSubscriber NewSubscriber)
{
    string status = string.Empty;
    // Add Subscriber...

    return status;
}` How do I set NewSubscriber.Email to the email parameter in the webservice?

Comment: It also gave me a warning saying "type or namespace name `NewSubscriber` could not be found...

Comment: How do I utilize the Reference.cs file? It appears to have everything I need? Do I need to upload it to my web server as well?